# How to put a button over a Div with overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have a box and want to put the button over the box.

I have tried with z-index, grid-content, etc and the button is not showing over, the button has to be inside the box.

Html:

```css
#content {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
}

input[type='button'] {
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <input type="button" value="Click me!" />
</div>
```

I expected the button go over the box and the button has to be inside the box.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: You can just run the code snippet and you see the problem the button is still inside the box, and dont go over the box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try like this.

```css
#content {
width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }
#box{
width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
}
input[type='button']{
position: absolute;
    right:-30px;
    z-index:1000;
    float: right;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="box">
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Click me!" />
</div>
```

Comment: That is the answer that i was looking for thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your button position is relative to the parent `#content` that why is not showing outside to solve it you need to remove `overflow:hidden` or remove `position:relative` on `#content`

or you can wrap your div inside another div like this:

```css
#content{
width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: orange;
}
input[type='button']{
position: absolute;
    right:-30px;
}
.mainparent{
      position: relative;
  width:fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainparent">
<div id="content">
<input type="button" value="Click me!" />
</div>
</div>
```

the `.mainparent` div will take same `height` and `width` as `#content` div but with no `overflow:hiiden`

Comment: It has to be hidden.

Comment: @RampageProgramming your content  div is hidden but the mainparent div is not!

Answer (score 0):

With `overlow` property set to `hidden`, you have only one option: use `position: fixed` for the button and apply positioning relative to the window. Note that you'll need to readjust position on scroll.

```css
#content{
width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
}
input[type='button']{
    position: fixed;
    right:290px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

<input type="button" value="Click me!" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That `right: -30px` is putting the button outside the box. Give this a try:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #content {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            background: orange;
        }

        input[type='button'] {
            position: absolute;
            right: 30;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <input type="button" value="test">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It has to be over the box.